# How to generate dynamic Images using Neo4j api in Java

Tags: java, image, neo4j

I  worked on a scenario to genarate images using graphic2d in java. Now I have to work on the same scenario using Neo4j api. Can anybody help me out with this or provide me where I can find the relevant content. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [Graph Visualization](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/) page shows several ways to generate a visualization.

For example, the neo4j browser UI allows you to download a PNG of the results of a Cypher query.